# Switch an image using media queries in an HTML email not working

Tags: html, css, email, media-queries

I'm trying to switch out an image in an HTML email using media queries, but some versions of outlook are just displaying both images. Here's a simple version of my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

*[class].image {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
}

.headermobile{
    display: none;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px){ 
   .headerdesktop{
     display: none;
   }

   .headermobile{
     display: block;
   }
}   

</style>

</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<td>

<!-- DESKTOP -->

<img src="desktop.png" class="headerdesktop image">

<!-- MOBILE -->

<img src="mobile.png" class="headermobile image">

</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

It seems to work alright on mobile devices, but I'm not sure what I'm missing for desktop.

Comment: Which versions of Outlook? Have you checked if those versions support media queries?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
  <img src="mobile.png" class="headermobile image" style="mso-hide:all;">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Putting the code as a condition for all email clients apart from outook will mean the image hiding will be dependent on media queries only. I have added a style to the image as well.

There is another method which requires a little more code and i will give that to you if this part doesn't work.

Please let me know if this works.

Cheers